# Communication between .html page and Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, html, raspberry-pi

I've got this Code and I want to create the possibility for anyone who visits my page, if a checkbox is checked, I want to communicate with my Raspberry Pi which the .html page will be hosted on [Pi will be the Access Point in which people will connect to and access the HTML page]. How may I do that? What code will I have to put under my if statements of the buttons, and what ways do you recommend for it to communicate?

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/59fHyah.png" id="checkbox" width="40" style="margin: 3.55cm 5.04cm"/>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/59fHyah.png" id="checkbox_1" width="40" style="margin: 3.55cm -0.70cm"/>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/59fHyah.png" id="checkbox_2" width="40" style="margin: 1.65cm -0.44cm"/>

<script>
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var checkbox_1 = document.getElementById('checkbox_1');
var checkbox_2 = document.getElementById('checkbox_2');
var img_1 = 'http://i.imgur.com/59fHyah.png';
var img_2 = 'http://i.imgur.com/zgwd1n1.png';
var img_3 = 'http://i.imgur.com/Mi1DQpC.png';

checkbox.onclick = function () {
    if (checkbox.src == img_1) {
        checkbox.src = img_2;
    } else if (checkbox.src == img_2) {
        checkbox.src = img_3;
    } else if (checkbox.src == img_3) {
        checkbox.src = img_1;
    }
}
checkbox_1.onclick = function () {
    if (checkbox_1.src == img_1) {
        checkbox_1.src = img_2;
    } else if (checkbox_1.src == img_2) {
        checkbox_1.src = img_3;
    } else if (checkbox_1.src == img_3) {
        checkbox_1.src = img_1;
    }
}
checkbox_2.onclick = function () {
    if (checkbox_2.src == img_1) {
        checkbox_2.src = img_2;
    } else if (checkbox_2.src == img_2) {
        checkbox_2.src = img_3;
    } else if (checkbox_2.src == img_3) {
        checkbox_2.src = img_1;
    }
}
</script>

<style>
body  {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/kcmsgdr.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your Raspberry will need to be hosting a server of some kind and your HTML will need to make http requests to it.

Comment: @yBrodsky How may I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/ybrodsky/raspberry-pi-expressjs-led-example Here you have an example. The code you care is in /routes/led.js, /routes/index.js and /views/index.html